# GIMP Python or C Script, Access Canvas Constantly in Background

Tags: python, c, gimp

I'm having some trouble determining if I can run a background process which accesses the current canvas continuously. Basically I'd like to monitor the existing canvas and pipe that information to a network protocol (NDI or something similar) so that I can "live edit" an image. Frame rate isn't incredibly critical here but I would like to do something better than what I'm currently doing which is capturing the screen and streaming it.

I can't seem to find any documentation on running a plugin that doesn't perform an operation and then terminate. Ideally I'd like to start the plugin and just let it sit in the background reading at a set schedule.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? The API and documentation doesn't have a lot of examples and my initial plugins basically opens a window and then dies.

As a point of reference I use GIMP to edit masks for projection maps and I'm always on the lookout to avoid using Photoshop. I'd like to create an open-source tool for the NDI tools that already exist in Photoshop (or a Syphon/Spout option).

Comment: The plugin doesn't need to terminate. Gimp doesn't really care about ongoing plugins... There are plugins out there that are started and don't return to Gimp (a typical example is autosave plugins). OTOH I don't know of a mechanism that allows to you to access the image contents safely (ie, not being caught in the middle of an update by another action).